# Same bound on derivative of function and its inverse

Tags: analysis, functions, inverse

Imgine $f$ is a function (real or complex, doesn't matter) and $|f'(a)|\leq 1$, $|(f^{-1})'(a)|\leq 1$ for a given $a$ in the domain. Does this mean that $|f'(a)|=1$? Why?

Comment: This is false. Consider as a counterexample the identity map $f: [0;1] \to [0;1]$, $f(x)=x$

Comment: I agree that it is false, but I cannot see how $f(x)=x$ can be a counterexample. Surely in that case,  $|f'(a)|=1$ for every $a$ in the domain.

Comment: This would be true if you replaced the condition $|(f^{-1})'(a)|\leq 1$ with $$|(f^{-1})'(f(a))|\leq 1$$

Answer (score 3):

A valid counterexample could be $f(x)=x^2$ on $(0,\infty )$ where $f^{-1}(x)=x^\frac 12$

In this case...

$f'(x)=2x$ so $|f'(a)| \le 1$ for $a \in (0,\frac 12]$

$(f^{-1} )'(x)= \frac12 x^{-\frac12}$ so $|(f^{-1} )'(a)| \le 1$ for $a\in [\frac 14, \infty)$

so for $a \in [\frac 14 , \frac 12)$ both conditions hold but $|f'(a)| \ne 1$